# WordPress - cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds

Tags: wordpress, curl

So I'm new to WordPress and I just installed the BeTheme for a website, now I want to use a pre-built website to start.

When I go to the page and select any template and try to install it I receive the following error

```
cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds
```

I'm really new to this theme so kindly help me out in the briefest way possible
Thank you

Comment: did you checked by activating default themes like twentyseventeen, twentysixteen? BTW you cant install a template, only you can set the template to the page

Comment: the theme is installed. I am trying to install the pre-build website in the theme